gnome extension manager 0.5.0 doesn't find any extension
I need help. I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 and after installing several extensions the extension with the manager extension can't find any extension any more.

I try to reinstall the package: sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-shell-extension-manager
but it still doesn't work.
P.D.
i found this log: (/var/log/apport.log)
**INFO**: apport (pid 6027) 2024-07-01 00:59:41,501: called for pid 2439, signal 6, core limit 0, dump mode 1

**ERROR**: apport (pid 6027) 2024-07-01 00:59:42,502: gdbus call error: Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

**INFO**: apport (pid 6027) 2024-07-01 00:59:42,503: executable: /usr/bin/gnome-shell (command line "/usr/bin/gnome-shell")

**INFO**: apport (pid 6027) 2024-07-01 00:59:46,400: wrote report /var/crash/_usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.crash


There is no issue with the extension manager or your system,
The Gnome extension repository seems to be down as per this github issue comment.

Oh, thanks a lot, I would like to give a positive vote, but the platform won't let me, I must have a reputation greater than 15

You can accept the answer instead.
